# Are there any benefits in casting a convex program into a linear program?

Tags: soft-question, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I'm curious a relative broad question:

Suppose I have a convex program in hand. Hence, I could use many well-developed software packages to solve this problem for sure, e.g., CVX.

But, instead of using CVX, suppose I can recast the original convex program into a linear program. I was wondering if there is any benefit I can get from this recast linear program? Can I say I definitely get a better computational complexity? And is there any suggested paper/book related to my question that I can consult with?

Thank you.

Comment: If your problem has a polyhedral feasible set and a piecewise-linear objective, CVX *is* going to convert it to a linear program. Otherwise, you can't do it anyway.

Comment: It depends on the recasting. For example if you introduce exponentially many variables or constraints, then it will likely harm the run time complexity of the LP solver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience there are three practical reasons I want to do that:

- Linear solvers are often faster. E.g. Cplex LP is often faster than Cplex QP/QCP (same thing for Gurobi). Even more pronounced: MIP is faster than MIQCP.
- Linear solvers are often more robust. One reason may be because they have seen more LP problems than NLP problems.
- Gurobi and Cplex don't offer general convex solvers. I.e. some of the fastest solvers are geared towards LP/MIPs.

Of course if the linearized version of the model adds much more complexity (e.g. piecewise linear) then the above advantages may not outweigh this added complexity.